# I cannot install yum in my docker container

Tags: docker, rpm, yum, rhel

I have a `docker container` which was built by a `keycloak` image.

I want to install `vim` in the container but I found that I need to have `yum` in order to install the `vim`. I tried to download `yum` from the internet and use rpm to install it, but the container didn't have `sudo` to let me change the file permission.

Following is my linux version:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.0 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.0"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.0:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.0
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.0"
```

How can I get any text editor installed in the container?

Comment: Questions related to usage of programs are better suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 29):

Minimal RHEL 8 containers do not contain Yum (or DNF) because that requires Python, which inflates the size of an image quite a bit. However, it contains `microdnf` which is written in C and which has limited capabilities.

You should be able to do

```
microdnf install vim
```

or

```
microdnf install yum
```

Comment: It says I do not have a permission to create a folder and I cannot use sudo to change my permission because sudo is not found........

Comment: @miketsui3a did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 16):

- connect as a root to your container:

```
docker exec -u root -it <container> bash
```

*then install vim (or what you need) with

```
microdnf install vim
```

Comment: lovely stuff, awesome way out

Comment: Really helpful. you can pretty much install any command

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem and found a solution. In your `Dockerfile`, Try:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:8.0.1
USER root
RUN microdnf install <whatever>
```

HTH.

Comment: nice, because they run most of the commands using root user but just before the last command, they do `USER 1000`